# What is the error in int('253' ,4) python code?

Tags: python, valueerror

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 4: '253'
The Error in the code. Please explain why is it an error?

Comment: You cannot have a '5' in a base-4 number.  Just like you cannot have a '2' in a binary number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int('253',4)` will return value to base 4.

And the base 4 only containing value: `0,1,2,3`. You can take a look in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_numeral_system).

You provided `5`, that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Base 4 can use only {0, 1, 2, 3}. But you are using 5 in your number ('253')

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't use `5` in a base 4 number. The `int()` command takes in the number as the first parameter and then the base in which you want to convert it from, in this case `4`. Since base 4 numbers are just 0-3, `253` is not a valid base 4 number, and thus returns the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 4: '253'`,